# ActiveMQ embedded vs standalone performance

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jms, activemq-classic

We have a legacy system where ActiveMQ configured as part of the main app within one JVM.  Its already configured using tcp transport as follows

```
<transportConnector name="tcp" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?wireFormat.tcpNoDelayEnabled=true&amp;wireFormat.tightEncodingEnabled=false" />
```

We would like to change the architecture and separate ActiveMQ into a standalone JVM; There is some debate about in-process vs. out of process messaging.  Is there any impact in term of performance by doing that?

(Of course we will do performance test to review this approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have communication through TCP rather than the VM/in-memory transport so there should be no difference in performance.

The VM transport used in an embedded broker will probably be more performant.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is no internal optimization from the broker lib to realize within VM or out of VM setup as we specifically use TCP.